# capistrano deployment nightmare

Tags: git, capistrano

I am getting the followoing error when I try to do a deploy via a "deploy" user account.

```
  1782001..ae10d1b  master -> master
 ** transaction: start
  * executing `deploy:update_code'
    updating the cached checkout on all servers
    executing locally: "git ls-remote git@github.com:username/app_name.git master"
  * executing "if [ -d /var/www/app_name/shared/cached-copy ]; then cd /var/www/app_name/shared/cached-copy && git fetch -q origin && git reset -q --hard ae10d1bfe43820d8d69bbc92761a3f666cf56765 && git clean -q -d -x -f; else git clone -q git@github.com:username/app_name.git /var/www/app_name/shared/cached-copy && cd /var/www/app_name/shared/cached-copy && git checkout -q -b deploy ae10d1bfe43820d8d69bbc92761a3f666cf56765; fi"
    servers: ["173.230.158.13"]
    [173.230.158.13] executing command
 ** [173.230.158.13 :: out] error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied
 ** 
    command finished
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /var/www/app_name/releases/20100930022459; true"
    servers: ["173.230.158.13"]
    [173.230.158.13] executing command
    command finished
failed: "sh -c 'if [ -d /var/www/app_name/shared/cached-copy ]; then cd /var/www/app_name/shared/cached-copy && git fetch -q origin && git reset -q --hard ae10d1bfe43820d8d69bbc92761a3f666cf56765 && git clean -q -d -x -f; else git clone -q git@github.com:username/app_name.git /var/www/app_name/shared/cached-copy && cd /var/www/app_name/shared/cached-copy && git checkout -q -b deploy ae10d1bfe43820d8d69bbc92761a3f666cf56765; fi'" on 173.230.158.13
```

I can verify that I can do a "git clone" using the deploy account on the server and ssh to git@github.com

The same recipe works just fine if i specify "root" as the :user variable.

Here is my deploy.rb

http://pastie.org/1189919

**Also, I am not sure what exactly does the :group variable does in this recipe.**

```
drwxr-xr-x 14 deploy www-data   4096 2010-09-29 20:38 .
drwxr-xr-x 10 deploy www-data   4096 2010-09-29 20:38 ..
drwxr-xr-x  7 deploy www-data   4096 2010-09-29 13:13 app
-rwxr-xr-x  1 deploy www-data    240 2010-09-29 20:38 Capfile
drwxr-xr-x  5 deploy www-data   4096 2010-09-29 20:38 config
drwxr-xr-x  4 deploy www-data   4096 2010-09-29 20:38 db
drwxr-xr-x  2 deploy www-data   4096 2010-09-29 20:38 doc
drwxr-xr-x  9 deploy www-data   4096 2010-09-29 20:38 generate
drwxr-xr-x  8 deploy www-data   4096 2010-09-29 20:38 .git
-rwxr-xr-x  1 deploy www-data    156 2010-09-29 20:38 .gitignore
-rwxr-xr-x  1 deploy www-data    145 2010-09-29 20:38 .gitignore~
drwxr-xr-x  3 deploy www-data   4096 2010-09-29 20:38 lib
lrwxrwxrwx  1 deploy www-data     28 2010-09-29 20:38 log -> /var/www/voteable/shared/log
drwxr-xr-x  5 deploy www-data   4096 2010-09-29 20:38 public
-rwxr-xr-x  1 deploy www-data    457 2010-09-29 20:38 Rakefile
-rwxr-xr-x  1 deploy www-data  10011 2010-09-29 20:38 README
-rwxr-xr-x  1 deploy www-data     41 2010-09-29 20:38 REVISION
drwxr-xr-x  3 deploy www-data   4096 2010-09-29 20:38 script
drwxr-xr-x  6 deploy www-data   4096 2010-09-29 20:38 test
drwxr-xr-x  2 deploy www-data   4096 2010-09-29 20:38 tmp
-rwxr-xr-x  1 deploy www-data 810605 2010-09-29 20:38 uninstall
drwxr-xr-x  3 deploy www-data   4096 2010-09-29 13:13 vendor
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to make sure that you own .git so you should never do a checkout as root or you're going to run into this problem.

`chmod -R ug+rw .git` will fix the problem this time but you have to be diligent about keeping your coworkers from doing manual `git pull`s or work on setting up group permissions correctly.

Comment: Who is "you" in you own .git. the deploy account? Please see this other post of the same/similar problem as well.. may be related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3827331/strange-ssh-issues-with-github

Comment: You is your deploy account. If you do an `ls -la` on your .git/FETCH_HEAD you'll see that it's owned by root. So you'll either have to chown it to the deploy user, or chmod it so the deploy user can edit it.

Comment: yYou are absolutely correct. on that note..I updated the OP with the permission on my /www/var/app directory. Is that what it should look like or should www-data own it? I am very unclear about who should own this directory www-data or deploy

Comment: also my deploy account is in "nogroup" is that the way it should be?

Comment: probably want to make it www-data instead of nogroup. How about an upvote and an accepted answer if this worked?

Comment: No, that didn't work. I added deploy user to www-data group. Updated the OP with the permission on .git directory. still the same error

Comment: wait a minute..it did work. can you please verify that the permission on the app directory is correct? I do owe you many votes up :)